# Debate request. X Factor and other talent shows

Tags: discussion

I would like to start a debate on this site to see what peoples views are on programs such as X Factor that in my opinion are mass producing mediocre artists that barely last a year and these programs are killing the music industry...

Is such a debate on topic on this site or would it be closed off as opinion based?

Answer (score 6):

Debate is not Q+A, and the ethics of popular media are not on topic either. This discussion would be welcome in chat, of course.

Comment: ah that's helpful to know. how do i go about starting a chat?

Comment: nevermind scrolling to the bottom of the page answered that question haha

Comment: So folks know, Nathan created this chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17282/are-talent-shows-like-x-factor-killing-the-music-industry